# How to mock db in Scala Slick

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, slick

I am trying to mock db in a "Service" layer that is using Slick in order to Unit Test action composition in it.

Unfortunately I am not able to mock the db and `JdbcProfile` with Mockito. In particular I am not able to mock `JdbcProfile#API` in these lines of code:

```
  import driver.api._

  val dbConfig = databaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
```

Do you know a better strategy to unit test Slick (I don't want to use [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/))?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered mocking at a lower level?

personally I have a wrapper method that encapsulates the
Database.forDataSource call. In my tests I spy that method to return a mock[Database] which I can use for all my persistence layer tests.